# Converting a LINQ dynamic query to IQueryable in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to convert a LINQ query that joins two tables to `IQueryable` type in Entity Framework so I can further apply filter expression on it.

Here's the code:

```
IQueryable<Bill_Joined_V1> bills = 
     (from primary in _billEntity.BillTable
      join secondary in _billEntity.BillInfoTable on primary.BillID equals secondary.BillID
      orderby primary.BillID
      select new
                {
                    primary.BillID,
                    primary.CustomerID,
                    secondary.Name,
                    secondary.Value
                }).AsQueryable<Bill_Joined_V1>().Where(FilterExp);
```

The entity classes are as follows:

```
public class Bill_V1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid BillID { get; set; }

    public string BillTypeID { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User_V1 UserTable { get; set; }

    public double AmountDue { get; set; }
}

public class BillInfo_V1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long BillInfoID { get; set; }

    public Guid BillID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BillID")]
    public virtual Bill_V1 BillTable { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Dummy bill record for query purpose
public class Bill_Joined_V1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long BillRecID { get; set; }

    public Guid BillID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BillID")]
    public virtual Bill_V1 BillTable { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public virtual Customer_V1 CustomerTable { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

The code does not compile. It produces error message saying

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Is there a way to convert the LINQ query to `IQueryable` type without putting the query result to a physical table? How do I work around this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to call `.AsQueryable()`. `.Where()` is designed to return an IQueryable of appropriate type. But the exact type of IQueryable in your code won't be `IQueryable<Bill_Joined_V1>` because you are using an anonymous type. What you really need to do is *not* use an anonymous type here:

```
select new
                                {
                                    primary.BillID,
                                    primary.CustomerID,
                                    secondary.Name,
                                    secondary.Value
                                }).
```

Instead, do

```
select new Bill_Joined_V1 { /* initialize properties */ }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. Bill_Joined_V1 doesn't contain any records. Can you please elaborate on how to initialize properties? Thanks.

Comment: OK I think what you are misunderstanding is this: `.AsQueryable<Bill_Joined_V1>()` does not magically know how to do type conversion from an anonymous type to Bill_Joined_V1. Imagine that you do ToList() instead of AsQueryable(). What do you have? A collection of [anonymous type]. Now imagine AsQueryable is a method that converts from a *collection* to a queryable. Should that work?